# Send private message from firebase

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, socket.io

I'm new to firebase. my question is, in firebase realtimedb, i want to push private message from firebase. in socket io this can do from this way.
**// to individual socketid (private message)
io.to(socketId).emit(/* ... */);**
how can i do this in firebase, another thing is firebase realtime db has any privilege for dynamically update or add their rules

Comment: What does your db structure look like? You can simply add a node in db inside a user specific node and make sure the user is listening to it.

Comment: but what's the way to protecting that node from other users listening? and creating dynamic rules.

Comment: You can check user uid in security rules.  Can you update your question with db structure if any so it'll be easier to explain that way?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new node called notifications having child nodes with user IDs as key:

```js
{
  notifications: {
    user_id_1: { },
    user_id_2: { },
    user_id_3: { }
  }
}
```

If you need to send a notification to `user_id_1`, just add a new node containing the message to `notifications/user_id_1`. Make sure that user is listening to that node like this:

```js
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue} from "firebase/database";

const db = getDatabase();
const msgRef = ref(db, 'notifications/' + curUserId);

onValue(msgRef, (snapshot) => {
  const data = snapshot.val();
  // show the message
});
```

To make sure users can read their own messages you can use security rules:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "notifications": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```